# How can I delete keys in hash that don't exist as elements in array (Perl)?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key

I have an array of key names and need to remove any keys that are not in this list from a hash.

I gather deleting keys in a hash is a Bad Thing while iterating over it, but it does seem to work:

```pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array=('item1', 'item3');
my %hash=(item1 => 'test 1', item2 => 'test 2', items3 => 'test 3', item4 => 'test 4');

print(Dumper(\%hash));

foreach (keys %hash)
{
    delete $hash{$_} unless $_ ~~ @array;
}    

print(Dumper(\%hash));
```

gives the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'item3' => 'test 3',
      'item1' => 'test 1',
      'item2' => 'test 2',
      'item4' => 'test 4'
    };
$VAR1 = {
      'item3' => 'test 3',
      'item1' => 'test 1'
    };
```

What is a better/cleaner/safer way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use smartmatch `~~`, it's fundamentally broken and will likely be removed or substantially changed in upcoming releases of Perl.

The easiest solution is to build a new hash only containing those elements you're interested in:

```
my %old_hash = (
    item1 => 'test 1',
    item2 => 'test 2',
    item3 => 'test 3',
    item4 => 'test 4',
);
my @keys = qw/item1 item3/;

my %new_hash;
@new_hash{@keys} = @old_hash{@keys};  # this uses a "hash slice"
```

If you want to update the original hash, then do `%old_hash = %new_hash` afterwards. If you don't want to use another hash, you might like to `use List::MoreUtils qw/zip/`:

```
# Unfortunately, "zip" uses an idiotic "prototype", which we override
# by calling it like "&zip(...)"
%hash = &zip(\@keys, [@hash{@keys}]);
```

which has the same effect.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without a temporary hash to hold the slice??